# Where to get Oxygen in No Man's Sky

Tags: no-mans-sky

Just got No Man's Sky and enjoying it, but I have traveled to my first planet and am working on building a base as my instructions tell me.  A lot of stuff I need to craft need oxygen, and I have only found *ONE* plant that gives it. (a bulb type plant that spews acid).  This plant is kind of rare, and it doesnt show up as oxygen in my scans.  I'm surviving on Life Support Gel, but I need more oxygen.  What are all the different ways I can find oxygen?

Comment: I recommend stocking up on oxygen when you do find it -- expand your cargo space in your space suit and stick the essentials in there.

Comment: Yeah, following story right now, so following their instructions on what to craft/upgrade next, but will look into that.  Thanks.  =)

Comment: Well when you find directions to a drop pod, you should take a quick field trip. Not sure if the story line ever sends you in that direction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oxygen is spotted by bright red plants. The hazardous plantlife, like the bulb in your question is also a pretty decent source of it. To find Oxygen quickly you can do four main things

1. Use your Scanner, Oxygen will appear as red O² marks when you pulse it. You can upgrade your scanner with modules to increase it's effective range. Scanning Flora can also "unlock" Oxygen as the bonus resource.
2. Use your ship and fly low and slow. As I pointed out, Oxygen plants are bright red and universal no matter what planet you are on. You will be able to spot the plants from your ship. You can even shoot the plants with your ship to harvest directly.
3. Jump to a different planet. No Man's Sky is a stupid huge game, with basically near infinite possible planets. For all you know you've only seen "desert" planets and your next jump will be an Oxygen rich paradise.
4. Buy it. It's normally always in terminals and pretty cheap too, if you are absolutely out of life support and O² stores, hop to a station and stockpile some... Scanning some flora/animals should get you enough credits to buy a decent amount, even without bonuses.

Some other things you'll be able to do to get plenty of Oxygen later in the game

1. The Oxygen Harvester is a buildable that will essentially convert Carbon to Oxygen
2. The Atmosphere Harvester is also buildable, performs pretty much the same exact way as the Oxygen Harvester, but upgraded to improve efficiency and yield. This can collect other gaseous resources as well
3. The Gas Extractor is the final buildable. This behemoth uses power instead of fuel (like solar) and is a bit of a project to build and get going. but this will provide massive amounts of Oxygen. This can also harvest different gases depending on its location.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I may move to a different planet, because while the one I'm on has oxygen plants, their pretty spread out. The one thing is I'm not sure I want to leave my base.  I have been following the instructions, and have a refiner, teleporter, and research module, but the main reason those took so long was lack of oxygen.

Comment: oh, to gain resources from Flora, do i have to upload the discoveries first?

Comment: nope, once you scan the item with the analysis visor it will unlock the bonus resource.

Comment: Don't worry about leaving your base. Base computers are cheap to build, and the "starter" planet is usually a more hostile one, to teach you about hostile planets. These are normally not suitable locations for an ideal home.

Comment: Thanks.  Will try out some more planets in my system!

Comment: Found a lava planet with plenty of oxygen and carbon, and enough sodium to combat the heat.  Thnx for the help!